# How to move Magento core queues to RabbitMQ?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento-enterprise-2, rabbit-mq, message-queue

Magento has some core queues like:

- catalog_product_removed_queue
- codegenerator
- export
- inventory.mass.update
- inventory.reservations.cleanup
- inventory.reservations.update
- inventory.source.items.cleanup
- inventory_qty_counter_queue
- product_action_attribute.update
- product_action_attribute.website.update

Magento uses MySQL tables for managing asynchronous operations by default. Because these queues defined with `connection="db"` in `queue.xml`.

Is there a way to use RabbitMQ for these core queues without editing for Magento's core files like `vendor/magento/module-catalog/etc/queue.xml`. Can we override connection type of these queues?

Answer (score 6):

You should be able to override the connection type for these queues in env.php or config.php like so:

> #### Change message queue from MySQL to AMQP
>
> The following sample introduces a runtime configuration that allows you to redefine the adapter for a topic.

```
'queue' => [
    'topics' => [
        'product_action_attribute.update' => [
            'publisher' => 'amqp-magento'
        ]
    ],
    'config' => [
        'publishers' => [
            'product_action_attribute.update' => [
                'connections' => [
                    'amqp' => [
                        'name' => 'amqp',
                        'exchange' => 'magento',
                        'disabled' => false
                    ],
                    'db' => [
                        'name' => 'db',
                        'disabled' => true
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ],
    'consumers' => [
        'product_action_attribute.update' => [
            'connection' => 'amqp',
        ],
    ],
],
```

Source: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/message-queues/message-queues.html

Moreover, you can create your own module that has a queue.xml (or better yet, queue_consumer.xml, queue_publisher.xml and queue_topology.xml files) that overrides Magento's core values. This is possible, because the XML is merged according to the module loading order.